# How do I ensure that the macOS root account bug is fully fixed on my machine?

Tags: macos, security, password, accounts, root

There has been a large amount of confusion around [Security Update 2017-001,](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208315) especially due to rumors of the fix being reverted when running macOS version 10.13.1.

I am looking for a way to be fully sure that my Mac is protected. In this question I'll detail the steps I followed in trying to ensure that my device is secure, and note the conflicting information I have found which points to no precise answer.

---

Looking at the end of [Apple's support page related to this update,](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208315) I see:

> [If] you see MRTConfigData 1.27 in the Installations list under
>   Software in System Report, your Mac is also protected.

Under Software in System Report, the latest version I see of MRTConfigData is 1.26 dated December 1, 2017.

---

The second part of this paragraph also notes:

1. Open the Terminal app, which is in the Utilities folder of your Applications folder.
2. Type `what /usr/libexec/opendirectoryd` and press Return.
3. If Security Update 2017-001 was installed successfully, you will see one of these project version numbers:
   `opendirectoryd-483.1.5 on macOS High Sierra 10.13`
   `opendirectoryd-483.20.7 on macOS High Sierra 10.13.1`

Running the above command correctly lists `PROJECT:opendirectoryd-483.20.7` on my machine, which is indicated by Apple as the correct version.

---

If I attempt to reproduce the original bug by going to `Preferences > Users & Groups`, then clicking the lock icon and trying to log in as root using an empty password multiple times, the login dialog does not let me through.

The fact that I won't be allowed to log in as root no matter how many times I try gives me an indication that the issue might indeed be solved, but I   am still receiving conflicting information about this from my system.

[image: login as root]

---

In Directory Utility, when I open the Edit menu, I see the option `Enable Root User`. This tells me that the root user is currently disabled, which as far as I know is one of the conditions for triggering the bug: the `root` account gets enabled once you attempt to log in with it once, and then works without a password.

[image: Edit menu in Directory Utility]

---

Lastly, what is most suspicious is that in Directory Utility, when I search for root in `Directory Editor`, the root user account is listed with a password of `*`. Unless it is a placeholder for any password, this looks suspiciously similar to a one-character (or even empty) password. I am confused whether this means that a password for this account is set at all.

[image: root password]

---

How can I conclusively determine whether the root account issue is fully solved on my computer?

Answer (score 1):

You can't at this point. The security patch only runs once and Apple hasn't released a new full point installer that guarantees you're patched.

What you can do is set a secure root password and watch for log in attempts and successes and disable sharing until Apple releases a full OS point release with no need for a Security patch to be put on top of one or more unpatched full point releases.

My answer here stands:

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/307244/5472

If you can’t [install the official patch](https://support.apple.com/HT208315) or don't want to trust that it worked, then

### You don't want to disable root user on High Sierra only.

### To secure your Mac, enable root with a long secure password.

We are not changing this at work until the next full point release is out for macOS which would likely be 10.13.2

I reason that since this was a race condition and Apple pushed the patch so quickly - we're pretty sure it's solid, but what if you got the patch before you upgraded to 10.13.1 and now it needs that patch a second time or what if the installer didn't really do it's job. Low chance either happened, but only you know how bad a breach would be on your computer with someone having total control.